# how do I convert this Scheme code to Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to scheme. This is code sample from SICP course of MIT.

```
 (define (+ x y)
  (if (= x 0)
      y
      (+ (-1+ x) (1+ y))))
```

How do I convert this to Racket code? I want to convert to Racket because I am using DrRacket for running codes and I like that. It worked until now but complained about increment operators of scheme.

The errors I get are:

1. `define-values: cannot change constant variable: +`
2. `reference to undefined identifier: -1+`

Comment: What language are you using in DrRacket? Using a `#lang` based language (e.g., `#lang racket`), you can redefine primitives like `+` that are from the language. If you are using a student language, it will restrict you in order to provide better error reporting.

Comment: Just so you know, `#lang scheme` is an old backwards compatibility language. You probably want to just use `#lang racket`. I bet you're getting this error due to setting your memory limit too low or your program has a bug (e.g., infinite loop).

Comment: I wish this question to have an answer of how to run the above code in DrRacket IDE without manual translation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work fine in Racket:

```
(define (add x y)
  (if (= x 0)
      y
      (add (sub1 x) (add1 y))))
```

Some comments:

- The name `+` for the procedure will be troublesome, because it will clash with the primitive add operation in Scheme; it's simpler if you use a different name, like `add` (this will fix the first error)
- `-1+` is not a procedure in Racket, replace it with `sub1` (this will fix the second error). Optionally, you could define an alias for this procedure, like this: `(define -1+ sub1)`
- `1+` is not a procedure in Racket, replace it with `add1`. Optionally, you could define an alias for this procedure, like this: `(define 1+ add1)`
- Optionally: instead of `(= x 0)` you can write `(zero? x)`

Comment: You *can* define a `+` function -- it just means that you get your own definition in your own module.

Comment: @EliBarzilay agreed, I rephrased my answer. It's not that you _can't_, it's just inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the second error, change `(-1+ x)` to `(- x 1)` and `(1+ y)` to `(+ y 1)`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624878/777929) should help you with the first error.

If you want to use `-1+` and `1+`, you can define them yourself:

```
(define (1+ x) (+ x 1))
(define (-1+ x) (- x 1))
```

Comment: I'll see if I can figure it out when I get home today.